# If you have an unbreakable can that can be crushed really easily with liquid inside of it, would the liquid density change?

Tags: thermodynamics, pressure

Okay so basically imagine you have a can filled with water. This can not burst open no matter how much pressure is put on the can, but it can be crushed, and the liquid cannot burst out.

What would happen if you put many tons of pressure onto this can?

Answer (score 2):

There's no such thing as infinite tons of pressure, but as you increase the pressure on the contents (uniformy in all directions, as by submersion in a high pressure fluid), the volume of the contents (and magic indestructible container) will slightly decrease. The contents will increase in temperature and density. As it increases in temperature, heat will radiate, conduct, and convect away into the compressing fluid; so if we lower it slowly, it will stay about the same temperature as the surrounding fluid, while decreasing in volume and increasing in density. At extreme pressures not found in Earth's oceans, but present elsewhere in the solar system (for instance, deep below the clouds of Jupiter), water undergoes phase changes to exotic forms of high pressure ice.

Significant research has been done on high pressure water ices, but you'll reach the edge of human knowledge before you get to the highest pressure regimes known to exist in the Solar system. *Nature* has an article available for free [here](https://www.nature.com/articles/s42004-020-00349-2).